# Create a new localhost Git repository from already cloned Git?

Tags: php, git, github, laravel-4, composer-php

I would like to clone a Laravel 4 from Git [HERE](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) and after using a Composer to install all dependencies, I wish to create a new Git on my HDD where I have my Dropbox synchronized.

Is it even possible ?

After getting Laravel 4 being cloned into `C:/www/laravel-project/`, I would like to commit the whole project into my localhost REPO seating in `D:/Dropbox/REPOS/Git/` so it will become `D:/Dropbox/REPOS/Git/laravel-project/`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible fixes:

1. Edit .git/config so that your origin is your repo (replace `https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git` with `file:///D:/Dropbox/REPOS/Git/laravel-project/`).
2. Delete the `.git` directory and then run `git init` and `git remote add file:///D:/Dropbox/REPOS/Git/laravel-project/ origin`

The problem I've seen with local directory repos is that the `D:/Dropbox/REPOS/Git/laravel-project/` repo will need to be on a branch that will not be used (i.e. A DoNotUse branch).

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and give you my feedback.

Comment: Once I run `git remote add ...` I get an error: `fatal: remote origin already exist` but it's empty folder, no hidden files

Comment: You can run `git config --list` to see your remotes.  I've heard that with Windows, some remotes are added to the global configuration (default location: C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig and you can remove the `[remote "origin"]` section from that file).  Alternatively, you can run `git remote add file:///D:/Dropbox/REPOS/Git/laravel-project/ localRepo` so you can use `git push localRepo master`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two paths you can take to do this:

1. Change the origin to your "remote" and remove or rename the Laravel origin.
2. Preserve the Laravel origin and use a second "remote" for your files.

Option 1 is probably the easiest.

1. Go to `D:/Dropbox/REPOS/Git/laravel-project/` and do `git init` to make an empty git repo.
2. Go to your `C:/www/laraval-project/` folder and do `git remote -v` and save the URL for the current origin if you want to keep it.
3. Run the command `git remote origin set-url file:///D:/Dropbox/REPOS/Git/laravel-project`
4. Optional: run `git remote add github url-you-saved-from-step-2` so you can do `git pull github` if you want to update from the Laravel github
5. Run `git push -u origin master` and it should push into your Dropbox's git repo.

For Option 2 you just skip steps 2 through 4 and - run `git remote add dropbox file:///whatever` and change step 5 to `git push -u dropbox master` or whatever branch you want. Once you use `-u` once you can just do git push and it should push to whatever you set as your upstream with `-u`.